# Laravel: lang file in subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, localization

I want to "multilocalize" my Laravel project.

I made my directory structure like this:

```
lang
- en
 - front
  - contact.php
-footer.php
```

And I built my footer like this:

```
{{ link_to('/', trans('footer.frontpage'))}}
```

It works perfectly, but when I want localize the other blade pages, for example the `contact us` page like this:

```
@lang('front.contact.name')
```

or this:

```
{{ __('front.contact.name') }}
```

or this:

```
{{ trans('front.contact.name') }}
```

I only got back on the page:

> front.contact.name

What's the problem?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Just use `/` as directory separator.

```
{{ trans('front/contact.name') }}
```

> In Blade both "`/`" and "`.`" function (while the latter is recommended).
>
> But for `Lang` the "`.`" is *unintentionally* reserved for file's content (array and any number of child-array), so that we can have both a folder and file with the same name (like both `front` folder and `front.php` file).

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem :)

Comment: Wow, thanks for that answer! This seems completely undocumented, and is very inconsistent with blade's usual path handling. Did you arrive at it by reading the source?

Comment: Just a heads-up: From Taylor Otwell in the Laravel issue queue: ["This behavior is not intentional and thus may not be supported in the future so would rather not document it."](https://github.com/laravel/docs/pull/3957#issuecomment-355646321)