# How to get localization array values from sub folder?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6, laravel-localization

I have sample file structure in my app:
**Folders:**

```
lang->en->admin
```

Here I have sample localization file:

```
menu.php
```

Code in file:

```
<?php
return [
    'home' => 'Admin Dashboard',
];
```

How I can get `home` key value in blade?

I now tested this example code but not work:

```
{{__(admin/menu.home)}}
{{__(admin\menu.home)}}
```

Comment: try `admin.menu.home`

Comment: Error: `Use of undefined constant admin - assumed 'admin' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) `

Comment: My PHP version is `PHP 7.2`

Comment: let me try that

Comment: Ok, you can try it.

Comment: `{{__('admin/menu.home')}}` this working fine may be u are missing the single qoutes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: lang file in subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45657634/laravel-lang-file-in-subfolder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your views change this to

```
{{__(admin/menu.home)}}
{{__(admin\menu.home)}}
```

This

```
{{__('admin/menu.home')}}
{{__('admin\menu.home')}}
```